# torch.einsum doesn't accept float tensors?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, numpy-einsum

I get the following error:

> RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #3 'mat2' in call to _th_addmm_out

I use torch.einsum as follows:

`mu = torch.einsum('ijl, akij -> akl', idxs, activation_map)`

I don't understand this, as in the documentation they are using float tensors too (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html). Also choosing a long tensor is no option, as all values in `activation_map` are between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your first argument, `idxs` is of type `Long`.
All input tensors to `torch.einsum` should be `Float`.

Comment: Thank you so much, can't believe I didn't think about that. It's solved! :)

Comment: I will do that! :) but I have to wait 6 more minutes until I can accept an answer.